# How to install VQmod extension for opencart 2.0.x.x without using FTP

Tags: opencart2.x, vqmod

I have installed vqmod extension for opencart 2.0.1.0 from following link 
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501
I have followed installation steps till replaced files.
Now, how I should upload Opencart modifications on localhost.
On admin panel made following setting **System->Setting->Store Edit->FTP**
FTP Host : localhost

FTP Port : 22

FTP Username : XXXXXX

FTP Password : ******

FTP Root : C:\wamp\www\xxxx

Enable FTP : Yes

But still vqmod is not installed.So, where I am going wrong.
**Note**: I have made many changes in core files of opencart.
Hope so which doesn't affect vqmod installation. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have access directly to your server (localhost - WAMP server), I suggest to follow the official instructions from github.com (https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart) or try to follow my instructions below

First, you need to uninstall the one that you did, just navigate to /admin/controller/extension/ => Delete (backup first) installer.php and modification.php => Rename installer.php.original to installer.php and rename modification.php.original to modification.php

Second, to install vQmod for OpenCart 2:

1. Download [v2.5.1-opencart.zip](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases/tag/v2.5.1-opencart.zip)
2. Unzip it, inside you will find a folder named "vqmod"
3. FTP/Copy/Transfer "vqmod" folder to the root of your OpenCart installed folder (where you see: admin, catalog, image, system folders)
4. Make sure vqmod folder is writable (I guess you don't need to do this with WAMP server)
5. Then go to http://www.yoursite.com/vqmod/install - if you see a success message, then installation is done. If you see "index.php not writeable", then you need to set your root OpenCart index.php to writable. If you see "Administrator index.php not writeable", then make the "/Admin/index.php" to writable.

I believe for WAMP server (running under Windows), to make something writable = make sure that file don't have Read Only.

If you are not clear about something, just visit github page: https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart

If you still have issue, post comments.

Comment: :Thanks for reply.I tried steps according to your instructions but 5th step I see file **ugrsr.class.php 2014-10-01 21:32 13K** can u please suggest any other way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know other method. I guess you might try to google for your error or try to re-install it again.

Comment: Its working..I have change setting in **System->Setting->Store Edit->FTP**